# Match balanced occurrences of nested tag

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a test string:

`s = "A test [[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]] paragraph. wef [[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]] test"`.

I need to match the occurrences of the `[[...]]` parts of the string. There can be up to the second level of nested `[[ ]]` tags in the string (as shown in the test string).

I started with `/\[\[.*?\]\]/`, but that only matches the following:
`[[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]]` (it's missing the last occurrence of the `]]`.

How do I go about matching the remainder of each `[[ .. ]]` block? Is this possible with regex?

Comment: You want only the outer ones? Do you have single `[` or `]` inside?

Comment: What is the desired result for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have single isolated `[` or `]`, then it is pretty much simple. The following assumes no restriction on the nested level.

```
s.scan(/(?<match>\[\[(?:[^\[\]]|\g<match>)*\]\])/).flatten
```

returns:

```
[
  "[[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]]",
  "[[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]]"
]
```

Comment: Thanks @sawa! That works well. Now, I need to use this regex and combine it with another. I have a requirement where I need to match changes in text.

By default I match with `/\s/` so that I treat each change as a whole word. I need to modify this so that I match "all changes of words, treating `[[ .. ]]` blocks as whole words". An example output of `string.split(regex)` is: `["A", "test", "[[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]]", "paragraph."]`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex solution. I've assumed left (right) brackets always appear in pairs.

```
level = 0
s.each_char.each_cons(2).with_index.with_object([]) do |(pair, i), a|
  case pair.join
  when "[["
    level += 1
    a << i if level==1
  when "]]"
    a << i+1 if level==1
    level -= 1
  end
end.each_slice(2).map { |b,e| s[b..e] }
  #=> ["[[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]]",
  #    "[[you|n|note|content of the note with a [[link|n|link|http://link]] inside]]"]
```